Quasicompactness of $\operatorname{Proj}A$
$\newcommand{\Proj}{\operatorname{Proj}}$
Let $A$ be a graded ring of the form:
\begin{align}
A=\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty A_n
\end{align}
So in particular this ring is positively graded, but it is not necessarilly generated in degree one.
I am trying to figure out when $\Proj A$ is a quasicompact scheme, and I think it is true if and only if the irrelevant ideal $A_+=\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ satisfies:
$$\sqrt{A_+}=\sqrt{\langle f_1,\dots, f_n\rangle}$$
for some $f_i\in A_+$. I believe this because if $\Proj A$ is quasicompact, then every open cover by projective distinguished opens admits a finite cover, so for some set of $\{f_1,\dots, f_n\}\in A_+$ we can write that:
\begin{align}
\Proj A=\bigcup_i^nU_{f_i}\Longrightarrow V(A_+)=\bigcap_i^nV(f_i)=V(\langle f_1,\dots, f_n\rangle)
\end{align}
It follows that:
$$\sqrt{A_+}=\langle f_1,\dots, f_n\rangle$$
as desired.
I have trouble showing the other direction. Let $\{U_i\}$ be any open cover, and obtain a subcover of projective distinguished opens $\{U_{g_j}\}_{j\in J}$, where $J$ is some indexing set, then we have that:
$$V(A_+)=V(\langle g_j:j\in J\rangle)=V(\langle f_1,\dots, \rangle f_n)$$
implying that:
$$\sqrt{\langle g_j:j\in J\rangle}=\sqrt{\langle f_1,\dots, f_n\rangle}$$
But I am unsure of how to use to get a finite subcover of $\{U_{g_j}\}_{j\in J}$

I have figured this out.
By hypothesis we have that:
$$\sqrt{A_+}=\sqrt{\langle f_1,\dots, f_n\rangle}$$
hence:
$$V(A_+)=\bigcap_{i=1}^nV(f_i)$$
By taking compliments, it follows that:
$$\operatorname{Proj}A=\bigcup_{i=1}^nU_{f_i}$$
Each $U_{f_i}$ is an affine scheme, so $\operatorname{Proj}A$ is the union of finitely many quasicompact spaces, and thus must be quasicompact.
